# is this jquery faster?

Tags: jquery

I used to write this:

```
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassA');
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassB');
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).addClass('ClassC');

$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).children().each(function () {
 //do something here
});
```

and now I'm writing this:

```
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex)
  .removeClass('ClassA ClassB')
  .addClass('ClassC')
  .children().each(function () { 
      // do something here
  });
```

Is the latter going to run faster than the former? Just curious.

Comment: Why not try profiling it yourself?

Comment: sorry, but pretty obvious that the latter is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing's for sure, this codes FINDS the element each line:

```
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassA');
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassB');
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex).addClass('ClassC');
```

In chaining, if finding the element is just once, it is faster then:

```
$('#MyDiv .TheClass').eq(TheIndex)
  .removeClass('ClassA ClassB')
  .addClass('ClassC')
  .children().each(function () { 
  // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Query after query will be slow and inefficient.
Chaining is hard to read and harder to debug.

Here is another option:

```
   $MyDiv = $('#MyDiv .TheClass');

    $MyDiv.eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassA');
    $MyDiv.eq(TheIndex).removeClass('ClassB');
    $MyDiv.eq(TheIndex).addClass('ClassC');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try profiling it, however in this case the difference is fairly simple. In the first case, jQuery has to go and figure out what objects satisfy `$('#MyDiv .TheClass')` 4 times, whereas in the second case it only has to do that once, then simply passes the object to the next method. So yes, the second one is faster (not by much though).